# Finding two pairs of integer from an array with the same square sum

Tags: algorithm

I'm toubled with a algrithm problem:

You have to determine if there exists a number (not necessarily
in A) which can be written as a sum of squares of two distinct
numbers from A in two different ways (note: m^2+n^2 and n^2+m^2
counts as a single way) and which runs in time n^2 log n in the
worst case performance.

Could anyone help me, thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you made an attempt at reasoning about this or performing research?

Comment: Possible direction - give it a reasonable range to check and run recursively until either a result is detected or the base case recursion condition is met.

Comment: My idea is to use algorithm like merge sort on the square of each number with runtime O(nlogn), and so some add calculation with runtime O(n) inside the merge part.

Comment: You should put in the post the idea you have, not in a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in `O(n^2)` using a hash map. You go through each pair and populate a map with `(key,value)` as `key = sum of squares of elements in the pair` and 
`value = the tuple of elements`. Take care when comparing the new tuple and the tuple in the map and you can find the pairs. For example for the pairs `(a, b)` and `(x, y)` you would want to avoid the pairs where `a == x` and `b == y` and the other one is `a == y and b == x`.

Pseudo code:

```
for i = 1 to n in A:
   x = A[i]
   for j = i+1 to n in A:
      y = A[j]
      k = x^2 + y^2
      if ( map has key k ):
         v = get_from_map(k) // v is a tuple of elements whose sum of squares is k
         v1 = (v[1], v[0])
         if ( v != (x,y) and v1 != (x,y)) return (v, (x,y))
      else:
         put_in_map(k, (x,y))
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, I forgot the hash map.